# An integral and a Jensen-type formula

Tags: integration

For $f$ be analytic on the disc $\overline{D}(0,R)$ centred at $0$ with radius $R>0$ and such that $f(0)\neq 0$, then the following formula is well-known

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-i\theta}\log(|f(Re^{i\theta})|)d\theta=\frac{1}{2}R\frac{f'(0)}{f(0)}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\rho}\left(\frac{R}{\rho}-\frac{\overline{\rho}}{R} \right)
\end{align}

where $\rho$ are the roots in $D(0,R)$

I have been stuck trying to calculate the following integral where the above formula cannot be applied (directly). Suppose $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $M=|z_0|+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is as usual positive and small. What is then the value of the following integral

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-i\theta}\log(|z_0+2M \Im(z_0 e^{-i \theta})-Me^{i\theta}|)d\theta
\end{align}

I would be glad if anyone has suggestions, or can give some advice on reference

Comment: What is the “well known formula” in the earlier case?

Comment: \begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-i\theta}\log(|f(Re^{i\theta})|)d\theta=\frac{1}{2}R\frac{f'(0)}{f(0)}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\rho}\left(\frac{R}{\rho}-\frac{\overline{\rho}}{R} \right)
\end{align*} where $\rho$ are the roots in $D(0,R)$ I edit the post

Comment: with $w=e^{i\theta}$ use that $\Im(z_0 \bar w)=\frac{z_0/w-\bar z_0 w}{2i}$ and $\log |w|=0$ to transform the log integrand to $\log |z_0w-Miz_0+Mi\bar z_0 w^2-Mw^2|$ and the inside function $f(w)=z_0w-Miz_0+Mi\bar z_0 w^2-Mw^2$ is a quadratic so clearly analytic so you can apply the result above with $R=1$ and need find the roots of the quadratic inside the unit disc...

Comment: @Conrad thank you for the comment!